# String Formatting phone number with leading zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I just want to ask on how to String Format Phone number and retain the leading zeros in `razor` and `html` The one I tried trimmed the leading zeroes

`<text>@String.Format("{0:(###)###-####}", double.Parse(item.Phone))</text>`

The output is always `(42)123-4567` instead of `(042)123-4567`

Thanks!

Comment: `double.Parse` you say? What is `item.Phone` exactly? What type?

Comment: @MrLister Sorry to not include `item.Phone` datatype, it is in `string`

Comment: `"{0:(000)000-0000}"` - `#` means _replace corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string_

Comment: So if the input is already a string, why convert it to a double? Then you lose any zeroes at the start. Numbers by themselves have no leading zeroes.